# Full Width Content Bootstrap Row Not Centered

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a new website and I cannot seem to center one row that's supossed to be full width.

This is the site url: http://pixelkings.com/development/pixelkings/wordpress/

And the section named "our team" is the one I'm having issues with.

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you please provide any code? Link only questions are not good for future. Or are you going to leave the site as is forever for future refrence? Don't think so. The essential parts in fiddle or sth is more preferable. Otherwise this question is eligible for putting hold only.

Comment: Thing is is a Wordpress instance, so I don't generate the code at all. I can only copy-paste the source code from the page, which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `our-team-row` div has a margin-left of -90px. Just remove it and check if it works

Comment: if I remove that, and zoom out, all the content shifts to the right. It needs to be responsive

Comment: hmm can't you use a media query for bigger resolutions, zeroing the margin?

Comment: For the defaults, yes. I don't know how your code is being generated, but that margin-left is changing the offset of your carousel.